# Fyne import issue

Tags: user-interface, go, module, compiler-errors, installation

I have just started golang coding, and I don't know how to import module. I looked on the internet, and i found that line of code to write in the cmd.

```
    $ go get fyne.io/fyne
```

And now, in my disk there are some package. 
Then, i wrote this code:

```
    package main

    import (
        "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    )
    func main(){
        a:= app.New()
        w := a.NewWindow("Clock")
    }
```

But when i execute it, i have that error:

```
    exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Someone know where is the issue? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://fyne.io/develop/: "Fyne requires 3 basic elements to be present, the Go tools (at least version 1.12), a C compiler (to connect with system graphics drivers) and an system graphics driver. " gcc is the missing C compiler.

Comment: I already have a c compile, but  it is enought that it is installed or  have I to connect it to something?

Comment: The C compiler must be findable in your PATH environment variable. To find out, type "which gcc". If it prints a path, you are OK. If it prints nothing, you have to install it correctly using the package manager of your OS.